# Shifting Formulas When Copying in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to have Excel move an entire table containing formulas and shift the formulas to account for the new cell positions?  Whether I use paste special or regular paste I'm finding that the formulas still reference the original table.  Is there a way to have the references shift when pasting a table assuming all the formulas are self-contained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use relative references, e.g. `=SUM(A1:A5)` instead of absolute references `=SUM($A$1:$A$5)`. Also, avoid referring to (self-) named cells. References are relative by default, use the dollar sign `$` to make them absolute.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I suppose my question is how can I get around that?  Is there any way to copy the table and have the absolute references shift accordingly?  For example, if I have A2=2 and B2 = A2 - is there any way I can copy A2:B2 to other cells and have the reference now be, say, G10:H10?

Comment: Well, if you _want_ the formulas to shift, why not use relative references? In your example, you want H10 `=G10`?

Comment: @114 If you really want to shift absolute references, maybe [this](http://superuser.com/questions/400113/how-to-copy-paste-absolute-cell-references-temporarely-as-relative-references-in) question will help you? (I have not tried this myself.)

Comment: The reservation I have is that some of the formulas in the table fix a row and not a column or a column and not a row, and I would like these to function the same wherever the table is moved.

Comment: @114 Then mixed references would solve your problem? E.g. `$A1` (fixed column, relative row) and `A$1` (relative column and fixed row). See [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-HA102748979.aspx?CTT=1) for more details.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but I am using relative references and the same error occurs, although there is also an absolute reference that would need to be dealt with in either case.  The first question you linked to does seem to be the exact problem I'm having.

Comment: @114 Can you give a minimal example that doesn't work?

Comment: If I have A2 = $A$1 and move both cells the formula containing cell will still reference $A$1.  If I have a row of numbers A4,B4,C4 and fix A$4 and so on in the cells below to create a table of the same numbers in columns, then move this table anywhere else it will change the results.